# Why does this async program not interleave the output?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, threadpool

The following asynchronous program reads two files which have the first character in each line increasing from n = 1 to 63 and prints each line from the file. The printing is done in the method DisplayResult.

I expected the output to be interleaved since the two async methods ProcessReadWriteAsync are started in parallel. However, the output is not interleaved as shown below.

It looks like two or more DisplayResult methods cannot run at the same time but why is this the case when there should be several non-background threads ready to execute them and the Main non-background thread is not doing anything while waiting for the Task ProcessReadWriteAsync to complete?

```
public static async Task Main()
        {
            Task task1 = ProcessReadWriteAsync(@"/tmp/temp1Write.txt");

            Task task2 = ProcessReadWriteAsync(@"/tmp/temp2Write.txt");

            await task1;
            await task2;
        }

        public static async Task ProcessReadWriteAsync(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
            await ReadWriteAsync(filePath);

            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            } finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public static async Task ReadWriteAsync(string path, string text)
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, useAsync: true);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];

                int noOfCharactersRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                DisplayResult(buffer: buffer);
        }

        public static async Task ReadWriteAsync(string path)
        {
            await ReadWriteAsync(path, "");
        }

        private static void DisplayResult(byte[] buffer)
        {
            string DecodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            string[] strings = DecodedText.Split('\n');

            for (int index = 0; index < strings.Length;index++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strings[index]);
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
1. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
2. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
3. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
4. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
5. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
6. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
7. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
8. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
9. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
10. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
11. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
12. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
13. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
14. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
15. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
16. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
17. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
18. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
19. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
20. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
21. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
22. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
23. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
24. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
25. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
26. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
27. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
28. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
29. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
30. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
31. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
32. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
33. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
34. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
35. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
36. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
37. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
38. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
39. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
40. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
41. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
42. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
43. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
44. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
45. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
46. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
47. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
48. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
49. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
50. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
51. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
52. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
53. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
54. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
55. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
56. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
57. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
58. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
59. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
60. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
61. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
62. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
63. msdn.microsoft.c
1. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
2. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
3. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
4. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
5. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
6. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
7. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
8. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
9. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
10. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
11. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
12. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
13. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
14. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
15. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
16. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
17. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
18. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
19. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
20. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
21. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
22. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
23. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
24. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
25. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
26. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
27. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
28. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
29. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
30. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
31. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
32. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
33. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
34. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
35. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
36. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
37. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
38. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
39. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
40. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
41. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
42. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
43. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
44. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
45. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
46. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
47. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
48. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
49. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
50. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
51. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
52. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
53. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
54. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
55. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
56. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
57. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
58. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
59. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
60. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
61. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
62. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
63. msdn.microsoft.c
```

Update:

I changed the function DisplayResult to async and awaited it in ReadWriteAsync, and just as I expected the output is now interleaved as shown below:

```
1. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
2. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
3. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
4. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
5. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
6. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
7. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
8. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
9. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
10. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
11. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
12. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
13. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
14. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
15. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
16. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
17. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
1. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
2. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
3. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
18. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
19. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
20. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
21. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
4. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
22. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
23. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
24. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
25. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
26. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
27. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
28. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
29. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
30. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
31. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
32. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
33. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
34. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
35. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
36. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
37. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
38. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
39. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
40. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
41. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
42. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
43. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
44. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
45. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
46. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
47. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
48. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
49. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
50. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
51. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
52. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
5. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
6. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
7. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
8. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
9. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
10. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
11. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
12. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
13. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
14. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
15. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
16. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
17. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
18. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
19. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
20. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
21. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
22. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
23. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
24. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
25. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
26. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
53. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
54. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
55. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
56. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
57. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
58. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
59. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
60. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
61. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
62. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
63. msdn.microsoft.c
27. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
28. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
29. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
30. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
31. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
32. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
33. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
34. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
35. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
36. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
37. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
38. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
39. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
40. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
41. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
42. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
43. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
44. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
45. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
46. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
47. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
48. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
49. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
50. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
51. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
52. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
53. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
54. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
55. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
56. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
57. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
58. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
59. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
60. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
61. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
62. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
63. msdn.microsoft.c
```

So my suspicion that a single non-background thread executes both calls of DisplayResult was correct hence why the second DisplayResult call is blocked until the first completes, but I'm not sure why there is only 1 non-background thread available?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you use `Task.Run` to call `ProcessReadWriteAsync`? It's possible that the I/O are actually completing synchronously

Comment: @KevinGosse `Task.Run` takes delegates as an argument and I don't know how to use delegates so I can't test it. However, my understanding of `Task.Run` from the IDE's description is that it does the same thing as calling an asynchronous method, in other words it allows a synchronous method to be run as an asynchronous method? I've **updated** my question and the output when an async DisplayResult is awaited is interleaved just as I expect, so the behavior is different.

Comment: what did you changed to make `DisplayResult` async?

Comment: I also can't reproduce what you are describing. without changes to your code I get interleaved output. (I used an Console application with .net-core 3.1)

Comment: You might also want to output which thread prints the output to see if multiple threads are working.

Comment: Interesting. My program is also a console application with .net 3.1. I added the keyword async to `DisplayResult` and changed it's return type to `Task` and then awaited it's call.

Comment: @Ackdari I tried again and now the program with `void DisplayResult()` is interleaving the output, sometimes. I don't know what changed - may be I didn't run it enough times so the small sample size I was using only gave a non-interleaved result.

Comment: You haven't posted the definition of `Access.read`. I guess that it is not essential for your question. You could remove all the non essential parts and present a minimal example that reproduces the problem. It would be better that way.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I removed an unused method, all other parts are needed to understand the program. Access is a simple user-defined enumeration holding two constants 0 and 1 named write and read respectively.

Comment: What about the `if (access == 0)...` code path. Is it related to the problem in any way?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, basically I didn't want to write separate methods to perform a read and write so I wrote one method that can read or write to a file. The code path `if (access == 0)` (i.e. the enum Access write = 0) is needed for the method to know when to write, not read but that conditional statement is not true in the posted code since `Access.read` is passed to `ProcessWriteReadAsync.` So I guess I could remove it?

Comment: Yes, if you want to save time from anyone who would like to help in solving the problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias done. Thanks for the tips. I hope it's easier on the eye now.

Comment: Nice! There is also a `ReadWriteAsync(string path)` overload that is not used as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Disk Operation. Disk Operations are inherently Disk bound, not CPU bound. A bit of Multitasking is mandatory, as the operation will take long. But paralellisation will not help - and more likely be detrimental.

Throwing a bunch of requests against different parts of a rotating disk, is a giant resource waste - basically the drive as a whole spends more time moving the read head, then actually reading. Hence there are features like [Native Command Queing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing) that will straighten it out into a usefull, sequential read. Chances are this feature - or a similar one - detect the bad idea you are trying to follow. And try to salvage it to something halfway sensible.

I like to say "Multitasking has to pick it's problems carefully". If you do not, you end up with code that is more memory demanding, more complex (and thus prone to errors) and worst of all *slower* then a basic sequential thing. Disk and Network are extreme examples for those cases.

Comment: Okay that's nice to know, however I'm only interested in `DisplayResult` where the printing takes place and why there is only one non-background thread executing it.

Comment: *Disk bound* <--- You probably mean "I/O-bound".